# Unique custom formats in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to create a list of paragraph styles in TinyMCE that apply to paragraphs. A paragraph should only have one of the styles applied. So a paragraph can be either normal, lead or small. It should not be more than one at once.

This is what I've tried:

```
formats: {
    "p-normal": { block: "p", classes: "govuk-body" },
    "p-lead": { block: "p", classes: "govuk-body-l" },
    "p-small": { block: "p", classes: "govuk-body-s" }
},

style_formats: [
    { title: "Paragraph styles", items: [
        { title: "Normal paragraph", format: "p-normal" },
        { title: "Lead paragraph", format: "p-lead" },
        { title: "Small paragraph", format: "p-small" }
    ] }
]
```

If I make a paragraph normal and then change it to a lead paragraph it ends up looking like this:

```
<p class="govuk-body p-lead">Test</p>
```

And in the format dropdown both styles are ticked. **Can I make it so only one format can be active and previously applied formats are removed?**

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do this by using an event handler to act before the format is toggled and remove all formats applied where the cursor is.

Here is the event handler:

```
init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
    editor.on('BeforeExecCommand', function (e) {
        if (e.command === "mceToggleFormat") {
            var formats = this.formatter.matchAll(["p-normal", "p-lead", "p-small"]);
            for (var i = 0; i < formats.length; i++) {
                this.formatter.remove(formats[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You need to check for all the formats that are exclusive and then remove any that are applied. If you had more than one group of exclusive formats you'd need to check the group based on which format was being applied.